# Java Web Service Client - SOAPFaultException: Algorithmn suite Basic128RSASha512 is not registered

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I am new to Web Service client development and have been tasked to create a client in Java to call an web service outside of our organization.

I downloaded the WSDL and in the  section there is this:

```
<AlgorithmnSuite>
    <Policy>
       <Basic128RSASha512/>
    </Policy>
</AlgorithmSuite>
```

When I run the client I get the following exception:

SOAPFaultException: Algorithmn suite Basic128RSASha512 is not registered

Any insight on how to get past this error is greatly appreciated.

I found:
https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/main/systests/ws-security/src/test/java/org/apache/cxf/systest/ws/x509/SHA512PolicyLoader.java

But I do not know if that will help solve the problem -- and if it will I do not know how to implement it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.